# Show that $f(x,y) = \frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}$ when $x \neq y$ is discontinuous at the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Show that the following function is discontinuous at the origin
>   $(x,y)=(0,0)$
>
> $$
> \begin{equation}
> f(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y} &x\neq y\\
> 0  &x = y
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
> $$

Now I am taking $x=my\ (m \neq 1)$ and getting $f(x,y)$ as

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3+m^3x^3}{x-mx} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2+m^3x^2}{1-m}$$

which tends to zero showing that the function is continuous. But we need to show discontinuance, I am not getting any other substitution for $y$ that will prove discontinuity.

Comment: Nothing forces you to approach $0$ along a straight line. What if you approach along the path $y =  (1-ax^2) x$? (I've just picked this by looking at the form you get by picking $y = mx$ above, and then choosing the function $m(x)$ that would give a non-trivial limit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which tends to zero **showing that the function is continuous**

No, the existence of the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along *one* path does *not* show that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$. To prove continuity, you need to prove this limit exists (and has the same value) along *every* path to $(0,0)$.

Thus to disprove continuity, you only need to show the non-existence of the limit, or the existence of a limit with a value different from $f(0,0)$, along a single path to $(0,0)$. You already tested all linear paths, so try something that's not linear.

It might be helpful to use long division to write:
$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y} = x^2+xy+y^2+\frac{2y^3}{x-y}, \quad x \neq y.$$
The $x^2+xy+y^2$ portion *is* continuous at $(0,0)$, so the $\frac{2y^3}{x-y}$ portion is the discontinuous portion. Notice that the numerator is cubic in $y$, while the denominator is linear in $x$ and $y$, so (as you found) if $y$ is a linear function of $x$ then the numerator will approach $0$ faster than the denominator. To get a limit other than $0$, you want the numerator to approach zero no faster than the denominator, which suggests trying the path $y=mx^{1/3}$, or something that goes even slower like $y=mx^{1/4}$.

Comment: $y=mx^{1/3}$ or $y=mx^{1/4}$ won't work! they give limit $0$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) which tends to zero showing that the function is continuous.

No, that's not something you can conclude from these limits only. Limits along *all paths* have to be equal for the function to be continuous and that's not the case.

Finding a path which results in a non-zero limit will be sufficient to conclude that the function is not continous in the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Along the path $y=x-x^3$, the limit approaches to $2$.